# Android url custom scheme dosent work

Tags: android

I read all post about this, but i think all code is right (very simple), the links dosen't appear clickable for "Manager://xxxx" , in mail, in qr, in whatsappp... whats happend?

i try with only

```
<data android:scheme="CoC" />
```

but in whatsapp only work http links. Why!

```
 <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeFullscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".ALoginConnect">

        <intent-filter>
             <data android:scheme="CoC" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*" />
             <action   android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: How do you expect any app other than yours to know that "Manager://xxxx" or "CoC://xxxx" should be shown as a link?

Comment: The system have to do, like http in TextView ( in IOS works fine )